# Avoid extra tabs when generating Haskell code with ghc-mod

Tags: indentation, osx, tabs, haskell-mode

I'm following the Haskell Emacs Tutorial [here](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md) and Emacs is annoying me with the way it adds some extra `TAB` characters. E.g.

When I have this code:

```
data ExampleType = ExampleType Int Int

instance Eq ExampleType where
```

If I position myself in instance and execute `C-u M-t`, it generates

```
instance Eq ExampleType where
  x == y = _body
           x /= y = _body
```

Instead of:

```
instance Eq ExampleType where
  x == y = _body
  x /= y = _body
```

Anyone knows why the 2nd line is added with an extra `TAB`? How do you avoid Emacs doing this?

Cheers,
Galder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736107/emacs-started-adding-extra-tabs-in-when-i-paste-into-it-on-os-x/27736214#27736214). Adding the following to your init file avoids the issue:

```
;; Avoid extra TAB indents when pasting or auto-generating code
(electric-indent-mode 0)
```